# Unable to obtain ZoneOffset from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO,Europe/Berlin resolved to 2019-12-26 of type java.time.format.Parsed

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, jpa

I am trying to parse a string to an `OffsetDateTime` but getting the following error:

```
Unhandled exception.
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '26122019' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO,Europe/Berlin resolved to 2019-12-26 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Example of the string I am attempting to parse looks like `26122019` and the value in the database looks like `2018-08-31`.

I got another error prior that sent me on this path when while writing a JPA query for these values `@Param("filterEndDate") OffsetDateTime filterEndDate,`.

```
      DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
    OffsetDateTime fromDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(filterFromDate,formatter);
    OffsetDateTime toDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(filterEndDate,formatter);
```

then I adjusted my code

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("ddMMyyyy")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY, 0)
            .toFormatter()
            .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

and got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {InstantSeconds=1577318400},ISO,Z resolved to 2019-12-26T00:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

-----update 1----

code

```
LocalDate fromDate = LocalDate.parse(filterFromDate,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy"));
```

error

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-12-20' could not be parsed at index 2
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ? and what is your expected output ?

Comment: @Deadpool to query a database using JPA of a table that has a format of `2018-08-31`.

Comment: then just use `LocalDate` you don't need `OffsetDateTime`, like this `LocalDate.parse(inputString,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy"))

Comment: When I tried that I got an error saying ``` Parameter value [2019-12-20] did not match expected type [java.time.OffsetDateTime (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2019-12-20] did not match expected type [java.time.OffsetDateTime (n/a)]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am showing two ways.

### Parse into LocalDate and convert

To me the simple way would go like this:

```
    String filterFromDate = "26122019";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");
    OffsetDateTime fromDate = LocalDate.parse(filterFromDate, formatter)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(fromDate);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 2019-12-26T00:00Z

Since your string contains a date and no time of day and no offset, I am parsing into a `LocalDate`. Then I perform the conversion to `OffsetDateTime` afterwards.

### Adjusting your advanced formatter to do the job

The way you tried can be made to work with just a simple adjustment:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("ddMMyyyy")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
            .toFormatter();
    OffsetDateTime fromDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(filterFromDate, formatter);
```

The result is the same as before. java.time distinguishes between an offset and a time zone. In many places an offset can be used where a time zone is required, but not here. Your call to `withZone()` provided a default time zone, but no default offset. Instead I am using `.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)` to establish a default offset.